# Proving an inequality related to Lebesgue integrals and bounded domains.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain ($|\Omega| < \infty$, where $|\cdot|$ represents the Lebesgue measure), $1 \leqslant p \leqslant q < \infty$, $0 \leqslant \lambda, \mu \leqslant n$ such that

$$ \frac{\lambda - n}{p} \leqslant \frac{\mu-n}{q}, $$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary. My goal is to show that

$$ \left( r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy\right)^{1/p} \leqslant c \left( r^{-\mu} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^q \, dy \right)^{1/q},$$

for every $ r > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$, where $c$ is some positive constant ($c > 0$).

**My attempt.** It seems to me that the only way to approach this problem is to apply Hölder's Inequality with exponent $q/p$. Doing so, one obtains that

$$ \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \left( \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^q \, dy \right)^{p/q} \, |B(x,r) \cap \Omega|^{1-p/q}. $$

Now, I try to use the fact that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in order to find the constant $c$. With this in mind, I use the bound $|B(x,r) \cap \Omega| \leqslant |\Omega|$ to conclude that

$$ \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \left[ |\Omega|^{1/p - 1/q} \left(\int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega}|f(y)|^q \, dy \right)^{1/q} \right]^p $$

or, equivalently,

$$ \left( r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega}|f(y)|^p \, dy \right)^{1/p} \leqslant r^{-\lambda/p} |\Omega|^{1/p - 1/q} \left( \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^q \right)^{1/q}. $$

Now, if I could guarantee that $r^{-\lambda/p} \leqslant r^{-\mu/q},$ the proof would be complete and I would conclude that the constant $c$ is just $|\Omega|^{1/p - 1/q}$. The problem is that I don't think we can guarantee that $r^{-\lambda/p} \leqslant r^{-\mu/q}$. Let me elaborate:

By hypothesis, we know that

$$ \frac{\lambda - n}{p} \leqslant \frac{\mu - n}{q}. $$

Solving this for $-\lambda/p$, we have that

$$ 0\geqslant-\frac{\lambda}{p} \geqslant -\frac{\mu}{q} + \frac{n}{q} - \frac{n}{p},$$

which doesn't allow me to conclude that $-\lambda/p \leqslant -\mu/q$, since $n/q - n/p \leqslant 0$.

With this in mind, I am posting this question in order to find any possible mistake that I've done or to find another approach to this problem.

I am mainly looking for hints and not full answers.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do not delete your question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find the Q&A helpful.

Answer (score -1):

We need to assume that
$$
\frac{\mu-n}q - \frac{\lambda-n}p \ge 0 \ge \frac{\mu}q - \frac{\lambda}p.
$$
The first inequality is an assumption in the question. The second is necessary to prove the claim. At the end there is a counterexample to the claim if $\frac{\mu}q - \frac{\lambda}p>0$.

By this assumption, there is $s\in [0,1]$ such that
$$
s(\frac{\mu-n}q - \frac{\lambda-n}p) + (1-s)( \frac{\mu}q - \frac{\lambda}p) =0
$$
or equivalently
$$
s( \frac np- \frac{n}q) +  \frac{\mu}q - \frac{\lambda}p =0.
$$

Using H"older inequality
$$
r^{-\lambda} \int_{B_r \cap \Omega} |f|^p 
\le  r^{-\lambda} \ \left(\int_{B_r\cap \Omega} |f|^q \right)^{p/q} |B_r\cap \Omega|^{1-\frac pq} .
$$
We continue with
$$
|B_r\cap \Omega| \le |B_r|^s |\Omega|^{1-s} \le c\ r^{ns} .
$$
Then we get
$$
r^{-\lambda} \int_{B_r \cap \Omega} |f|^p 
\le c\ r^{-\lambda} \ \left(\int_{B_r\cap \Omega} |f|^q \right)^{p/q} r^{ns(1-\frac pq)} 
$$
so that
$$
\left(r^{-\lambda} \int_{B_r} |f|^p \right)^{1/p}
\le c\ r^{-\frac\lambda p + s(\frac np - \frac nq) + \frac\mu q}\left(r^{-\mu} \int_{B_r} |f|^q \right)^{1/q}.
$$
The exponents add up to zero, hence we get the desired inequality
(without restrictions on $r$):
$$
\left(r^{-\lambda} \int_{B_r} |f|^p \right)^{1/p}
\le c\  \left(r^{-\mu} \int_{B_r} |f|^q \right)^{1/q} \quad \forall r>0.
$$

---

If you do not like additional assumptions, there is bad news:
if $\frac{\mu}q - \frac{\lambda}p>0$ then the only $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$-function satisfying the claim for all $r>0$ is $f=0$.

Suppose  the desired estimate
$$
\left(r^{-\lambda} \int_{B_r} |f|^p \right)^{1/p}
\le c\  \left(r^{-\mu} \int_{B_r} |f|^q \right)^{1/q}.
$$
is valid for all $r>0$. Rearranging gives
$$
\left( \int_{B_r} |f|^p \right)^{1/p}
\le c \ r^{-\frac\mu q + \frac\lambda p } \left( \int_{B_r} |f|^q \right)^{1/q}.
$$
For $r\to\infty$, the terms in brackets converge to the $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$- and $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ norm of $f$ (extend $f$ by zero to $\mathbb R^n$). Hence if $f\in L^q(\mathbb R^n)$ then the right-hand side converges to zero, hence $f=0$.